# VSTS IIS Web App Deploy fails with return 2148734720

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I configured releases same way for a couple of our servers but I have issue with one of them (others work perfectly):

[error]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.

[error]Error: C:\vstsagent\A2_work_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.20\MSDeploy3.6\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 2148734720

Unfortunately I can't find anything helpful related to this error Code.

My release configuration:

1. IIS Web App Deploy (Preview)
2. Deployment group with one specific staging server (I'm using on-premise agent)
3. Website name: correct name of my website in IIS
4. Virtual Application: empty field
5. Package of Folder: zip chosen from build drop artifacts
6. Selected "XML variable substitution"
7. Selected "Remove Additional Files at Destination"

What I've already tried with no luck:

- manually turn of application
- delete all files in application folder
- changing user account to use for the service

Again - same configuration for other servers works fine.

Servers configuration: Windows Server 2012R2 Standard x64

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and post the detail log here.

Comment: Thx, starain! Here is detailed log: https://pastebin.com/VZBVHZQh

Comment: Base on the log, there is the error log file C:\vstsagent\A2\_work\r1\a\error.txt, post it here. If the file will be deleted after building, you can add Copy Files task to copy it to other folder.

Comment: I can't find that file. Please notice this is release definition (build is going well). Is there any way to copy this error.txt before it is deleted? 

[error]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
[debug]{}
[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=C:\vstsagent\A2\_work\r1\a
[debug]rm -rf C:\vstsagent\A2\_work\r1\a\error.txt
[debug]removing file
[debug]task result: Failed

Comment: Logon agent machine and try to open it manually before be deleted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. .NET Framework 3.5 was missing on my server...

I was investigating logs and I found out that below line is causing failure.

```
"C:\vstsagent\A2\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.20\MSDeploy3.6\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A2\_work\r2\a\temp_web_package_8269135298977384.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='httproot'
```

So I copied it to CMD and got proper Windows message when I tried to execute it.

Comment: Is .net 3.5 a specific requirement? I am facing same error on deploy to a Windows 10 machine which already has .net 4.6.2 installed

Comment: In my case it deployed successfully but VSTS reports the above error which sucks because getting IT to install .NET on a Production Server isn't easy. As It requires a restart

Comment: Is this really THE answer here?  .Net 3.5 came out 10 years ago 2007.  Its support ended in 2011, why in the world would this be a dependency for the IIS Web App Deploy task in 2017?  There has to be a better solution here...

Comment: @raterus Indeed it seems like that. Fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Had the same issue. Installing .NET 3.5 fixed it :(

Comment: Same here. Thx for the tip!